# Packing a C struct in C++

Tags: c++, c

I need to use below `c` code in my `c++` visual studio project:

```
typedef PACKED(struct) _type1Struct
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b[1];
} type1Struct;

typedef PACKED_STRUCT{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
  } type2Struct;
```

for `PACKED` I created this, and it compiles fine:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

#define PACKED( __Declaration__ ) __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) __Declaration__ __pragma( pack(pop))
...
```

tried to do something similar for `PACKED_STRUCT`  but it **doesn't compile**:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define PACKED_STRUCT __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) struct __pragma( pack(pop))
...
```

what am I missing? how can I make it work?

Comment: That seems strange, since it looks like `PACKED_STRUCT` is the same as `PACKED(struct)`. Try to come up with a [mre] which produces the error message you get.

Comment: I've tested this on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fsdehW7WT), but haven't been able to reproduce your issue at all. There doesn't appear to be any error in what you've written, and no settings I have are capable of reproducing it. I'm expecting your compilation error is unrelated to these `struct`s in particular - however, without knowing what the error is or what the rest of the code is, it isn't plausible to determine what is wrong.

Comment: `uint8_t b[1];` Seriously? An array of 1 char? Are sure that isn't a workaround for `uint8_t b[];` and the size of the `b` array is stored in `a`? This is not possible in C++ (although compilers tend to allow it) and you should handle that struct in C files.

Comment: Note: packed in general is a very bad idea. You are better of writing a function to copy the not-packed struct to and from a buffer.